# yii2 localurls - language appended at the end of the url

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-extension

I am using Yii2 and the extension [localurls](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls)

I have followed the instructions but it seems the language is appended to the end of the URLs instead of before the script name:

> http://localhost/yii/advanced/frontend/web/index.php/en

Also, I have tried to disable the option "showScriptName" and the URL:

> http://localhost/yii/advanced/frontend/web/en

is not found -> 404 not found. Why so?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable pretty urls.

```
 ...
'urlManager' => [
    ...
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    ...
]
...
```

You should also have correct rewrite part in your web server config.

Comment: I have done that, and I get the 404 error, like I said. I don't understand why

Comment: Thank you! got the answers!

Comment: Thanks;) I understood that it's your issue after giving answer